# Test class compilation error Claim and ClaimParticipant

Tags: apex, code-coverage, compile-error

I am creating test class involving Claim and ClaimParticipant standard objects. While inserting these records, I am getting errors like `Variable does not exist: Name` and `DML requires SObject or SObject list type: Claim`. Adding the code where I am inserting records for reference.

```
    Claim obj = new Claim();
    obj.Name = '1234';
    insert obj;
    
    ClaimParticipant cp = new ClaimParticipant();
    cp.ClaimId = obj.Id;
    cp.Roles = 'Involved Driver';
    cp.ParticipantAccountId = acc.Id;
    insert cp;
```

I have also confirmed the field API name `Name` exists in Claim object. I am able to create records from UI. But not somehow able to create records in test class.

Comment: Do you have an apex class or variable called Claim? This would hide the `Schema.Claim`. You can, of course, qualify reference to the SObject by explicitly prefixing with `Schema.` like I did here, or you can rename the Apex class or variable.

Comment: Thank you Sir! That resolved my problem. Please add your comment as an answer so I can mark it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an apex class or variable called `Claim` this will hide the `Schema.Claim`. You can, of course, qualify reference to the `SObject` by explicitly prefixing with `Schema.` or you can rename the Apex class or variable.